# fragment_main xml missing in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have come through fragment_main_xml which is used to create dynamic UI.
But there is no option to choose blank activity with fragment in android studio.
I want to make 2048 clone.I have to use fragment_ main_xml for the UI to get adjusted to different screen sizes.But its not available by default.What should I do? please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout file named fragment_main.xml in /layout/ folder of your project.

Comment: But it creates fragmentmainactivity.what to do with it

Comment: If you just create android layout  xml file, no other file will be created. Do not create a new Activity. File > New > XML > Layout XML File

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a blank XML file, like the one below -

> article_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

And similarly create a Fragment Class which will be a subclass of Fragment, code below -

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}
```